# Assistance with Dash Table in Visualization using Plotly

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am currently working on a project where I need to visualize data using Dash and Plotly. Specifically, I have two data frames - one containing IP addresses and another containing corresponding values. Each Names is associated with a device, and after performing some backend parameter checks, I have created a set of values.

My goal is to display this information in a Dash table with a 10x10 layout. Each cell in the table should represent an Names , and the background color of each cell should reflect the values obtained from the data frame of the values.

I have attached the Python code I've been working on, but unfortunately, I'm facing difficulties in displaying the table as intended. I have been trying to implement this using Dash and Plotly, but I'm unable to achieve the desired 10x10 table layout

```
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
from dash import dash_table
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
data = {'Name': ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4', 'Name5','Name6', 'Name7', 'Name8', 'Name9', 'Name10','Name11','Name12'],
        'Value': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 80, 90, 70, 100, 50, 120]}

# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create the Dash app
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

# Define the layout of the app
app.layout = html.Div([
    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='table',
        columns=[
            {'name': 'Name', 'id': 'Name'},
            # You can add more columns if needed
        ],
        style_data_conditional=[
            {
                'if': {'filter_query': '{{Value}} > 30'.format(value)},
                'backgroundColor': 'blue',  # Change the color as needed
                'color': 'white',  # Change the text color as needed
            } for value in df['Value']
        ],
        style_header={
            'backgroundColor': 'rgb(230, 230, 230)',
            'fontWeight': 'bold'
        },
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
    ),
])

# Run the app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Hop this result like this table:

[image: hop this result like this table]